# How to uninstall newer version of java and install older version?

Tags: java

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Now I have a Java application which says

> A different version of Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is required to use this application.
>   and it is 1.6.0_17...

What to do?

Comment: ... What OS are you asking about?

Comment: 1.6.0_26 should usually work for 1.6.0_17. what message do you get when executing your java program?

Comment: ubuntu 11.04 ..it takes me to oracle site.

Answer (score 2):

It's really strange that the software you are trying to run requires a very specific update release (such as Oracle Java 6 update 17). Update releases are compatible and there should not be a need to require a very specific release.

On [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) you can download earlier versions of Oracle's Java implementation, including Java 6 update 17.

Comment: Do I need to remove the java currently on my system?

Comment: No, you can have multiple version of Java installed as you like, as long as they are installed in different directories. Also you need to make sure the software you're trying to run uses the version that it needs. How to do that depends on the software.

Comment: There are very valid reasons for using a particular version of java, and this is really for support purposes for particular applications which require a certification base on a specific tech stack. Better to have the same certified setup then items not certified by the application vendor.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to have different version of the application running, then the keyword java needs to be fully provided with a path.

one good way is to export the java_home before you run the application and have the application always read the java home when starting the server.

```
export JAVA_HOME = c:\jdk7
JAVA_HOME/bin/java -server ...

export JAVA_HOME = c:\jdk6
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to uninstall your current version of java and install the desired version. 
You can found all previous version of java on [this (Java Older versions)](http://help4j.com/download/java) location.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows you can directly uninstall and install the older version.

Note: we can use multiple versions in a system by changing the system or user environment variable to use some version as my current java version make or put the path as followed it should be pasted first in path

[image: System environment variable path setting]

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_12\bin;.;
```

[;.;] this will indicate as current working directory and this version will only take as default version while installing java dependent sofware installations ex:netbeans,tomcat etc